coredns helm chart and minio dns zone resolution failure
I have a minio running in the minio ns:
➜ kgsvcn minio
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
minio           ClusterIP   172.20.182.115   <none>        9000/TCP   25m
minio-console   ClusterIP   172.20.103.127   <none>        9001/TCP   25m

I need to forward all requests *.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local to pods behind svc minio.minio
However I'm getting the following errors:
bash-5.1# nslookup tekton-logs.minio.minio
Server:     172.20.0.10
Address:    172.20.0.10#53

*** Can't find tekton-logs.minio.minio.svc.cluster.local: No answer

cordns configmap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |-
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
            ttl 30
        }
        prometheus 0.0.0.0:9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
    minio.svc.cluster.local:53 {
        log
        whoami
        errors
        kubernetes minio.svc.cluster.local {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough
            ttl 30
        }
        cache 30
        reload
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: coredns
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: coredns
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: coredns
    eks.amazonaws.com/component: coredns
    helm.sh/chart: coredns-1.31.0
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: CoreDNS
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system

coredns helm values
servers:
  - zones:
      - zone: .
    port: 53
    plugins:
      - name: errors
      - name: health
        configBlock: |-
          lameduck 5s
      - name: ready
      - name: kubernetes
        parameters: cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        configBlock: |-
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
          ttl 30
      - name: prometheus
        parameters: 0.0.0.0:9153
      - name: forward
        parameters: . /etc/resolv.conf
      - name: cache
        parameters: 30
      - name: loop
      - name: reload
      - name: loadbalance
  - zones:
      - zone: minio.svc.cluster.local
    port: 53
    plugins:
      - name: log
      - name: whoami
      - name: errors
      - name: kubernetes
        parameters: minio.svc.cluster.local
        configBlock: |-
          pods insecure
          fallthrough
          ttl 30
      - name: cache
        parameters: 30
      - name: reload

logs

➜ klo -l app.kubernetes.io/name=coredns -n kube-system
[INFO] 10.120.142.100:42080 - 55062 "A IN tekton-logs.minio.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 163 0.000243657s
[INFO] 10.120.142.100:39235 - 64661 "AAAA IN tekton-logs.minio.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 163 0.000297776s
[INFO] 10.120.142.100:39235 - 64401 "A IN tekton-logs.minio.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 163 0.000155817s
[INFO] 10.120.142.100:38826 - 37249 "A IN tekton-logs.minio.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 163 0.00018647s
[INFO] 10.120.142.100:38826 - 37718 "AAAA IN tekton-logs.minio.svc.cluster.local. udp 53 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 163 0.00085907s

What am I missing or did wrong?
